# Whats the name of the tinymce button that disables/enables the display of html elements?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, wysiwyg

I totally forgot the name of that button, that disables the names of the elements, like h3 headings, paragraphs and the likes, look at the picture.
[image: Those ugly names on top of the actual content]

I'm looking for the name that you put on the init function for tinymce.

My full tinymce_setup.js

```
function CustomFileBrowser(field_name, url, type, win) {

    var cmsURL = '/admin/filebrowser/browse/?pop=2';
    cmsURL = cmsURL + '&type=' + type;

    tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
        file: cmsURL,
        width: 980,  // Your dimensions may differ - toy around with them!
        height: 500,
        resizable: 'yes',
        scrollbars: 'yes',
        inline: 'no',  // This parameter only has an effect if you use the inlinepopups plugin!
        close_previous: 'no'
    }, {
        window: win,
        input: field_name,
        editor_id: tinyMCE.selectedInstance.editorId
    });
    return false;
}

tinyMCE.init({

    // Init
    mode: 'textareas',
    theme: 'advanced',
    skin: 'grappelli',

    // General
    //accessibility_warnings: false,
    browsers: 'gecko,msie,safari,opera',
    dialog_type: 'window',
    editor_deselector: 'mceNoEditor',
    keep_styles: false,
    language: 'en',
    object_resizing: false,
    media_strict: true,

    // Callbackss
    file_browser_callback: 'CustomFileBrowser',

    // Layout
    width: 758,
    height: 300,
    indentation: '10px',

    // Cleanup
    cleanup: true,
    cleanup_on_startup: true,
    element_format: 'xhtml',
    fix_list_elements: true,
    fix_table_elements: true,
    fix_nesting: true,
    forced_root_block : 'p',

    // URL
    relative_urls: false,
    remove_script_host: true,

    // Content CSS
    // content_css : "css/example.css",

    // Plugins
    plugins: 'advimage,advlink,fullscreen,paste,media,searchreplace,grappelli,grappelli_contextmenu,template',

    // Theme Advanced
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location: 'top',
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align: 'left',
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location: 'bottom',
    theme_advanced_buttons1: 'formatselect,styleselect,|,bold,italic,underline,|,bullist,numlist,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,grappelli_adv',
    theme_advanced_buttons2: 'search,|,pasteword,template,media,charmap,|,code,|,table,cleanup,|,image,|,fullscreen,|,ibrowser,',
    theme_advanced_buttons3: '',
    theme_advanced_path: false,
    theme_advanced_blockformats: 'p,h2,h3,h4,pre',
    theme_advanced_resizing: true,
    theme_advanced_resize_horizontal: false,
    theme_advanced_resizing_use_cookie: true,
    theme_advanced_styles: 'Image Left=img_left;Image Right=img_right;Image Block=img_block',

    // Style formats
    // see http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/style_formats
    style_formats : [
        {title : 'Paragraph Small', block : 'p', classes: 'p_small'},
        {title : 'Paragraph ImageCaption', block : 'p', classes: 'p_caption'},
        {title : 'Clearfix', block : 'p', classes: 'clearfix'},
        {title : 'Code', block : 'p', classes: 'code'}
    ],

    // Templates
    template_templates : [
        {
            title : '2 Columns',
            src : '/path/to/your/template/',
            description : '2 Columns.'
        },
        {
            title : '4 Columns',
            src : '/path/to/your/template/',
            description : '4 Columns.'
        }
    ],

    // Adv
    advlink_styles: 'Internal Link=internal;External Link=external',
    advimage_update_dimensions_onchange: true,

    // Grappelli
    grappelli_adv_hidden: false,
    grappelli_show_documentstructure: 'on',

    extended_valid_elements : "iframe[src|width|height|name|align]", 

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some playing around, I was able to find a solution that worked for me.

The button to turn this feature on/off is located in the far right on the second row of the Grappelli TinyMCE theme:

[image: Show/Hide Document Structure]

The value of this button (on/off) is stored in a cookie (this is important, as I was pulling my hair out trying to figure out why my changes to remove this were not working)

**To completely remove this feature**

I don't think I'll ever need to make use of this button's functionality, so I decided to completely remove it.
In your **tinymce_setup.js** file, locate this line

```
grappelli_show_documentstructure: "on"
```

and change it to

```
grappelli_show_documentstructure: false
```

This sets the button's state to "off" on initial load. Now remember that it's most likely that the button's state has been set to "on" in your cookie, so if you try refreshing the page and it's still displaying, it's due to the value in your cookie being read and used to display this option on. Either turn off the button (which will change the value in your set cookie), or clear your browsers' cookies.
After I had ensured the cookies value was set to off, as mentioned, I had no future use for this button, so to remove it from your tray, we want to remove the *grappelli_documentstructure* button from our window tray - look for the following line

```
theme_advanced_buttons2: 'search,|,pasteword,template,media,charmap,|,code,|,table,cleanup,grappelli_documentstructure'
```

and simply remove the **grappelli_documentstructure** button

```
theme_advanced_buttons2: 'search,|,pasteword,template,media,charmap,|,code,|,table,cleanup'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not totaly sure which button you mean but i suggest you have a look at the tinymce demo page and you sdould be able to find your button there: http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php

Comment: How to disable the display of those H3, Paragraph, Paragraph, i know i disabled at some point, but i can't remember how.

Comment: please post your full tinymce config